# how to build wolfssl shared lib on ubuntu x64?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, 64-bit, wolfssl

on **ubuntu x64**, I try to compile the `wolfssl`

steps:

1. `./configure --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-openssh --enable-opensslextra`
2. `make`

But there is no shared lib generated. It only works on 32bit system.

why?

Answer (score 1):

@myd620 I just tested this on both Mac OS X and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (both 64-bit architectures).

**UBUNTU 14.04 LTS**

(wolfssl-root)/src/.libs/ contains both:

```
Jan 19 11:55 libwolfssl.a        <- static
Jan 19 11:55 libwolfssl.so.3.6.0 <- shared
```

**Mac OS X**

```
Jan 19 11:52 libwolfssl.3.dylib <- shared
Jan 19 11:52 libwolfssl.a       <- static
```

What is the output of this command on your system?

```
./config.status —version
```

Mine is:

**UBUNTU 14.04 LTS**

```
wolfssl config.status 3.10.0
configured by ./configure, generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69,
with options "'--enable-static' '--enable-shared' '--enable-openssh' '--enable-opensslextra'"

Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This config.status script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
```

**Mac OS X**

```
wolfssl config.status 3.10.0
configured by ./configure, generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69,
with options "'--enable-static' '--enable-shared' '--enable-openssh' '--enable-opensslextra' 'CC=gcc'"

Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This config.status script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
```